# If two masses are hung, how come the downward tension of mass A = upward tension of mass B?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

In this diagram, supposing the masses are at rest, how Tension 2 or T2 wold be equal to Tension 3 or T3.

[image]

Comment: Because of Newton's 3rd law

Comment: @BobD That can't be a (direct) application of Newton's 3rd Law, because Newton's 3rd Law talks about a pair of forces that act on *different objects*, whereas these are forces that are both exerted *by one object*, the rope. As explained in the answer by basics, this equality is actually an *approximation* that follows from the fact that we can safely ignore the mass of the rope as long as it's much smaller than the masses of the objects it's attached to.

Comment: @march My statement assumes massless inextensible string as is generally assumed unless otherwise stated . Thus the equal and opposite forces are between the two masses

Answer (score 3):

From the equilibrium of a **massless** rope. The only way to be in equilibrium (sum of forces acting on the rope = 0), is that the tension at the extreme points is equal.

Then, the force acting on the bodies, due to the rope, is opposite to the tension at the extreme points.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, assuming massless strings, the two forces have to be equal and opposite due to Newton's 3rd law. But we can reach this conclusion by drawing free body diagrams (FBD) on (1) the combination of the two masses, (2) on M1 and (3) on M2, as shown in figures 1,2, and 3 below.

*Note that since we have assumed a massless string between the masses, it has no "weight" pulling down on M1. The only forces acting down on M1 are its own weight and the tension in the string due to the weight of M2.*

Since the masses are in equilibrium, the net force on each must be zero per Newton's 2nd law, as shown in the equations below each FBD.

$$T_{1}= (M_{1}+M_{2})g\tag{1}$$
$$T_{1}=T_{2}+M_{1}g\tag{2}$$
$$T_{3}=M_{2}g\tag{3}$$

Substituting $T_1$ from eq (2) into eq (1) we obtain

$$T_{2}=M_{2}g\tag{4}$$

From eqs 3 and 4 we see that

$$T_{3}=T_{2}=M_{2}g \tag{5}$$

Hope this helps.

[image]